# My Application crashes when playing a sound

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I am trying to play a sound on the click of a button. But when I run the app it crashes and I get `Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT`.

This is my code:

.h file

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface HljodViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{

}

-(IBAction)playsound;
```

.m file

```
-(IBAction)playsound {

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Geese_4" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.numberOfLoops = 1;
    [theAudio play];
}
```

Comment: Added an [general exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010433-CH1-SW1).

Answer (score 1):

No one can tell you how to solve your issue if you don't capture the `NSError`. I suggest you do the following:

```
NSError *outError = nil;
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&outError];
if (outError)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [outError localizedDescription]);
}
... // continue on to happy time
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourfile" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSError *error;
AVAudioPlayer *sound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:&error];
[sound play];
```